# InteractiveMode | Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject | Method has zero rva

Tags: f#, json.net

> Env: OS-X / Xamarin Studio 6.1 / F# Interactive for F# 4.0

**Compiled:** The following works fine as compiled:

```
type Movie = {
    Name : string
    Year: int
}

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let movies = [
        { Name = "Bad Boys"; Year = 1995 }
    ]
    let json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movies)

    System.Console.WriteLine json
    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

**Interactive:** In interactive mode Newtonsoft.Json' JsonConvert.SerializeObject fails

```
type Movie = {
    Name : string
    Year: int
}
let movies = [
    { Name = "Bad Boys"; Year = 1995 }
]
let json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movies)
```

**Output:**

```
val movies : Movie list = [{Name = "Bad Boys";
                             Year = 1995;}; {Name = "Bad Boys 2";
                                             Year = 2003;}]

 System.BadImageFormatException: Method has zero rva
 File name: 'System.Net.Http.Formatting'
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0015>.$FSI_0015.main@ () [0x00006] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in <filename unknown>:0 
 [MVID] 7747cf446af449e194e4b4e70d85e773 2
 [MVID] eddc6e27796e462ba5a0f4fbcf15e179 0
```

I am missing some setup or does Newtonsoft.Json not work in F#'s Interactive mode.

*Note: I am using Xamarin Studio to add all references automatically to the interactive session (152 of them)*

#### Update:

Using Xamarin Studio:

- Edit / Send references to F# Interactive:

Which includes:

```
--> Referenced '/Users/sushi/code/sushi/GeneticGraphDatabase/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1/lib/net45/Newtonsoft.Json.dll' (file may be locked by F# Interactive process)
```

**JsonConvert.SerializeObject Produces:**

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Method has zero rva
```

**Referencing it 'manually' with the same assembly path:**

```
#r "/Users/sushi/code/sushi/GeneticGraphDatabase/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1/lib/net45/Newtonsoft.Json.dll";;
 --> Referenced '/Users/sushi/code/sushi/GeneticGraphDatabase/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1/lib/net45/Newtonsoft.Json.dll' (file may be locked by F# Interactive process)
```

**Works as expected:**

```
val json : string = "[{"Name":"Bad Boys","Year":1995}]"
```

Comment: Could you try referencing Newtonsoft.Json DLL directly using `#r` ? Perhaps Xamarin automatically loads a wrong version....

Comment: @TomasPetricek Thanks, that does work (see **Update:** section in question). Strange as I used the same assembly path that Xam. Studio "auto" referenced... I'll report it to Xamarin as an issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing `Json.Net` **'manually'** using the same assembly path that Xamarin Studio is using when using the menu item: `"Edit / Send references to F# Interactive"`

```
#r "/Users/sushi/code/sushi/GeneticGraphDatabase/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1/lib/net45/Newtonsoft.Json.dll";;
 --> Referenced '/Users/sushi/code/sushi/GeneticGraphDatabase/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1/lib/net45/Newtonsoft.Json.dll' (file may be locked by F# Interactive process)
```

**Works as expected:**

```
val json : string = "[{"Name":"Bad Boys","Year":1995}]"
```

**Bugzilla:** https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43307